# How do I add a like button to my facebook page and change the name to a company name?

Tags: facebook

I noticed some facebook company pages like:

```
http://www.facebook.com/companyname
```

Can change the persons name to the company name and also add a like button. How does one achieve these two things?

1. Add a like button to a company page of a URL like this - http://www.facebook.com/companypage
2. Add a like button on that page?

Answer (score 0):

You need a special account designed for business, you cant just do it to a personal account.

https://www.facebook.com/business/overview

Comment: I did that. I created a page but when I go to the company URL I made it still shows the person's name who created the account. I don't know how to make the company page the default page for the company URL.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach enough likes on Facebook you can get your own "short page-link". You only need a few likes (100-200 I think it is).

A like button is already on your page. However you can add an extra tab using HTML and Iframes to a remote document with a like button. The like button is found on Facebook's dev pages.

Comment: I already have the short page link. It's the following format - http://www.facebook.com/companyname  ... But it shows my real name instead of my company name.

Comment: That's crazy that facebook is this hard to use, I think I'm going to have to hire someone lol.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Code in HTML for Like Button
Detailed steps mentioned on the page on how to embed
You can add various styles too and a code will be generated for you

Comment: Providing links and library recommendations is fine. But you should include enough code or explanation in your answer to address the original question using your references. So, for instance, how does the OP—or someone with the same question—establish a company name?